# Mage error on saving a customer

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, session, fatal-error

This is occurring whenever I press "Save Customer" in the manage customers area in the Admin panel:

Error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Session.php on line 108
```

This error has come about after upgrading from `Magento 1.7.0.2` to `1.9.1`.

I realise this question may be a bit vague but all I'm after is some information on why I may be getting this error. I have done an amount of googling in the hope that this might be a common error, however no luck so far.

Any help in relation to how to track where this error is coming from or anyone with any knowledge on common problems with this sort of thing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Very strange. It seems that your autoloader cannot find Mage.php, which is required for everything you do in Magento. I'm assuming other things (anything) work?

Comment: Everything else functions fine, It's just on the customer management interface. Very strange.